# Creating new lists from valus inside another list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list which accepts user inputs. For example,

`List subjests=[];`

When the user add an input this list I want to create a list in the name of the new input.

For example when user add maths in to the List, I want a new List with maths as variable name

`List maths=[];`

Same for anything afterwords.
How am I supposed to do that in flutter?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23043669/8257908) for why you cannot create runtime variables in dart.

Answer (score 3):

Joy mentioned you can't create runtime variables in Dart. You are best off using the Map data structure to add and access lists using 1 predefined variable:

```
void main() {
  final Map<String, List> lists = {};
  lists["math"] = [];
  lists["science"] = [];
  print(lists);
}
```