# change any variable of a data class with the variable name as an argument

Tags: flutter, variables, repository

I am wondering whether I can create a function for my repository with which I can generically change any value within a variable which is based on a data class. Is this possible, how?

```dart
List<Task> tasks;

Future<void> changeTaskValue(int taskId, String variable, dynamic newValue) {
  task[taskId].<magic to get a reference to the variable> = newValue;
}

class Task {
  Task({this.taskId, this.taskName, this.status, });
  final int taskId;
  final String taskName;
  final String status;
}
...
void function abc() {
  changeTaskValue(taskId: 1, variable: 'taskName', newValue: 'test')
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically setting variable name in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039314/dynamically-setting-variable-name-in-dart)

Comment: not really, the other question is about dynamically creating variables, mine about modifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is you can't modify final variables. So what you can do is delete the `Task` object form the list and add another `Task` with the data you wanted.

```
List<Task> tasks;

Future<void> changeTaskValue({
  int taskId,
  String taskname,
  String status,
}) {
  tasks.remove(
    Task(taskId: 1), //id of the task you want to remove
  );
  tasks.add(Task(
    taskId: taskId,
    taskName: taskname,
    status: status,
  ));
}

class Task {
  Task({
    this.taskId,
    this.taskName,
    this.status,
  });
  final int taskId;
  final String taskName;
  final String status;
}

void abc() {
  changeTaskValue(taskId: 1, taskname: 'taskName', status: 'test');
}
```

Comment: good point, with final. I just copied some similar, handy class to write the example. Yes, It think your idea about providing the whole, updated task element is probably the easiest workaround

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to use MAP object

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> tasks;

  Future<void> changeTaskValue(int taskId, String variable, dynamic newValue) {
    tasks[taskId][variable] = newValue;
  }
```

Comment: Then I would have a different data structure. I was keen about a general method how to update nested classes within the repository from a bloc.

Comment: What you are looking for, isn't possible in Dart, you can check out this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737110/get-variables-name-by-its-value-in-dart-lang